# WHMCS and changing home link with variable

Tags: php, variables, navigation, whmcs

Hi and thank you for reading my post.

I have WHMCS installed with the ad-don multi-brand, what means I have multiple brands on WHMCS with one installation.
The URL is always http://billing.branddomain.com/. All of them have a main static website on http://www.branddomain.com/.

I want the home button to point to the static website, but the problem is that I cant put a static URL in the code as it is different per brand.
Therefore with PHP I am stripping the URL from the address bar, removing 'billing' and replacing it with 'www'.
Them I am trying to change the home link URL in the Main menu of WHMCS to this location. This is done by creating a PHP file in directory whmcs/includes/hooks

```
<?php
$aedit_just_domain = preg_replace("/^(.*\.)?([^.]*\..*)$/", "$2", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$aedit_homepageurl = "http://www.". $aedit_just_domain ."/";

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
   $redirect = $aedit_homepageurl;
   if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Home'))) {
           $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')
                       ->setURI($redirect);
   }
});
```

This doesnt work as for some reason I cant put a variable in there.
When I do:

```
<?php
use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
   $redirect = 'http://www.google.com/';
   if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Home'))) {
           $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')
                       ->setURI($redirect);
   }
});
```

This does work but now works with the static URL www.google.com.
Obviously I need this to be a variable as with $aedit_homepageurl.

Is there anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

`$aedit_homepageurl` is not accessible inside the function by default. 
You have 2 options:

1- You can use global keyword to access `$aedit_homepageurl` variable:

```
<?php
$aedit_just_domain = preg_replace("/^(.*\.)?([^.]*\..*)$/", "$2", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$aedit_homepageurl = "http://www.". $aedit_just_domain ."/";

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
   global $aedit_homepageurl;
   $redirect = $aedit_homepageurl;
   if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Home'))) {
           $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')
                       ->setURI($redirect);
   }
});
```

2- Move the top 2 lines inside the function:

```
<?php
add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
   $aedit_just_domain = preg_replace("/^(.*\.)?([^.]*\..*)$/", "$2", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $aedit_homepageurl = "http://www.". $aedit_just_domain ."/";

   $redirect = $aedit_homepageurl;
   if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Home'))) {
           $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')
                       ->setURI($redirect);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I made it work with the 2nd option. Can't believe I hadn't thought about that myself. I already spent 20 hours puzzling. You saved me from another 20 hours of puzzling.